# Get method works in Servlet, POST method does not

Tags: java, servlets, post

I'm a coding newbie and am trying to set up a web form which can collect information using a post method.

I've used an online tutorial to create the following servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloForm extends HttpServlet {


  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Using GET Method to Read Form Data";
      String docType =
      "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
      "transitional//en\">\n";
      out.println(docType +
                "<html>\n" +
                "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
                "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
                "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
                "<ul>\n" +
                "  <li><b>First Name</b>: "
                + request.getParameter("first_name") + "\n" +
                "  <li><b>Last Name</b>: "
                + request.getParameter("last_name") + "\n" +
                "</ul>\n" +
                "</body></html>");
  }


//Method to handle POST method request.
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
 }

}
```

My html form is below. When I change the method to GET - the form works. However when I change the method to POST I get HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="HelloForm" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
<br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried @Override on the post method as suggested in some other threads - but that didn't work.

Can someone suggest what may be going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using tomcat you may try this

```
<servlet-mapping>
     ...
    <http-method>POST</http-method>

</servlet-mapping>
```

in addition to servlet-name and url-mapping in your web.xml servlet configuration.

Answer (score 0):

your code contains some error due to that code gives error.

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);  // method calling is incorrect
}

Comment: Thanks - What should it be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code in the POST function.

Furthermore, why don't you use JSP? It is of good proclivitie to use the MVC approach when dealing with servlets.
I.e, Model - View - Controller

Pass the code to a JSP(View) and from there make the neccessary code.

Good luck!